# Parameter Type Mismatch with UrlFetchApp Payload

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, payload, urlfetch

I'm receiving the error: Passed parameter type mismatch: 'fields' when I try to do a POST request using Google Apps Script.

I've tried adding `JSON.stringify(requestBody)` on the payload and that didn't work either. Where am I going wrong here?

```
 var fields = ["id","name","group_name"]

  var requestBody = {
    "project_id": "3259344",
    "fields": fields,
    "limit": "30"
} 

  var options =
      {
           'method'  : 'POST',
           'headers' : {
           'User-Id' : email,
           'Authorization' : 'Bearer '+ apiKey
           }, 
          'payload' : requestBody
      };


var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.test.com/v2/json/get/keywords", options);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the detail specification of the API you want to use. So from the error message in your question, how about the following 3 modification patterns?

### Pattern 1:

#### Modified script:

```
var fields = ["id","name","group_name"];
var requestBody = {
  "project_id": "3259344",
  "fields": fields,
  "limit": "30"
};
var options = {
  'method'  : 'POST',
  'headers' : {
    'User-Id' : email,
    'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + apiKey
  }, 
  'payload' : JSON.stringify(requestBody),  // Modified
  'contentType': 'application/json'  // Added
};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.test.com/v2/json/get/keywords", options);
```

### Pattern 2:

#### Modified script:

```
var fields = "id,name,group_name";  // Modified
var requestBody = {
  "project_id": "3259344",
  "fields": fields,
  "limit": "30"
};
var options = {
  'method'  : 'POST',
  'headers' : {
    'User-Id' : email,
    'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + apiKey
  }, 
  'payload' : JSON.stringify(requestBody),  // Modified
  'contentType': 'application/json'  // Added
};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.test.com/v2/json/get/keywords", options);
```

### Pattern 3:

#### Modified script:

```
var fields = "id,name,group_name";  // Modified
var requestBody = {
  "project_id": "3259344",
  "fields": fields,
  "limit": "30"
};
var options = {
  'method'  : 'POST',
  'headers' : {
    'User-Id' : email,
    'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + apiKey
  }, 
  'payload' : requestBody
};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.test.com/v2/json/get/keywords", options);
```

### Reference:

- [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)

Comment: Thanks so much fo taking the time to answer my question. Unfortunately, I'm still receiving the same error. This is the API: https://topvisor.com/api/v2/

Comment: Sorry, pattern 1 has actually worked. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Andrew Charlton Thank you for replying and testing the scripts. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.